# unable to display google map on ruby on rails app page in production environment in local machine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I have problem over coffee script file  I Have written for gmaps I am using puma server in my rails5 application. my application consists of only one page which has google map. I have written all the scripts for maps in a file called home.coffee. when i run the same in development environment it runs fine but as soon as I start application in production mode it stops working. I have also made   config.assets.compile = true in production.rb file and also done assets precompiled  and starting server using command rails s -e production. any one help me out why it is not loading page.  I am attaching up my files along with question. It is unable to load even application.js file so it has issue of Javascript.San any body help me ou on my javascript coffee file If anybody can help me out, I would be great thank [Brower[while running on development mode][1\full.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ0rU.png)

production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require gmail_api
//= require home
//= require markerclusterer
//= require infobox
//= require turbolinks
// require_tree .
```

home.coffee file

```
# main function

map_initialize = ->
  #default marker
  marker = new (google.maps.LatLng)(28.7041, 77.1025)
  # customizing marker
  icon =
    url: 'assets/test.png'
    scaledSize: new (google.maps.Size)(30, 30)
    origin: new (google.maps.Point)(0, 0)
    anchor: new (google.maps.Point)(0, 0)
  # default options
  mapOptions =
    center: marker
    zoom: 2
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  # initializing map
  map = new (google.maps.Map)(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),    mapOptions)
  # restricting map to zoom level 2
  minZoomLevel = 2
  map.setOptions
    minZoom: minZoomLevel
    maxZoom: 15
  google.maps.event.addListener map, 'zoom_changed', ->
    if map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel
      map.setZoom minZoomLevel
    return
  # array of multiple locations
  locations = [
    {
      lat: 12.9716
      lng: 77.5946
    }
    {
      lat: 20.4925
      lng: 73.1350
    }
    {
      lat: 21.1702
      lng: 72.8311
    }
   ]
  # respects a left and right side boundary
  allowedBounds = new (google.maps.LatLngBounds)(new    (google.maps.LatLng)(-90, -150), new (google.maps.LatLng)(90, 150))
  lastValidCenter = map.getCenter()
  google.maps.event.addListener map, 'center_changed', ->
    if allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())
      lastValidCenter = map.getCenter()
      return
     map.panTo lastValidCenter
    return
  # locating different markers on map
  markers = locations.map((location, i) ->
    new (google.maps.Marker)(
      position: location
      icon: icon)
  )
   markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, imagePath:   'assets/m')
  #dialogbox for each marker
  infoWindowContent = []
  infoWindow = new (google.maps.InfoWindow)
  markers.map (marker, i) ->
    infoWindowContent.push [ 'Dialog Box ' + (i + 1).toString() ]
    google.maps.event.addListener marker, 'click', do (marker, i) ->
      ->
        infoWindow.setContent infoWindowContent[i][0]
        infoWindow.open map, marker
        return
    return
  return

# function to disable zooming

disable = ->
  map_initialize()
  map.setOptions
    draggable: false
    zoomControl: false
    scrollwheel: false
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true
  return

# function to enable zooming

enable = ->
  map_initialize()
  map.setOptions
    draggable: true
    zoomControl: true
    scrollwheel: true
    disableDoubleClickZoom: false
  return

$ ->
  map_initialize()
  return
```

Comment: Did any error printed in logs?

Comment: What's the result of `curl http://localhost:3000` in your command line?

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

Comment: No error in logs   just the response on server is C168s-iMac:gmap c168$ rails s -e production
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.1 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop

Comment: window.map_initialize()    solved the problem for me